# Table with merged cells appearing one by one in beamer

Tags: tables, beamer, multicolumn

I'd like to make a simple table appear its cells one by one in beamer, but somehow I'm getting a "misspaced \omit". Related topics are about missing & etc., which is not my case (the table displays fine without the \onslide).

Here's the code

```
\begin{tabular}{|l|r||l|r|}
\hline
\onslide<2->{\multicolumn{2}{|c||}{\textsc{Actif}}} & \onslide<2->{ \multicolumn{2}{c|}{\textsc{Passif}}}\\ 
\hline
\hline
\onslide<3->{Banque} & \onslide<3->{18550} & \onslide<4->{Capital} & \onslide<4->{18550}\\
\hline
\onslide<5->{\textbf{Total}} & \onslide<5->{18550} & \onslide<5->{\textbf{Total}} & \onslide<5->{18550}\\
\hline
\end{tabular}
```

Answer (score 1):

Move the `\onslide` command into the `\multicolumn`, like this:

```
\documentclass{beamer}
\setbeamertemplate{navigation symbols}{} % Has anyone ever used these?
\begin{document}
\begin{frame}
\begin{tabular}{|l|r||l|r|}
\hline
\multicolumn{2}{|c||}{\onslide<2->{\textsc{Actif}}} & \multicolumn{2}{c|}{\onslide<2->{ \textsc{Passif}}}\\ 
\hline
\hline
\onslide<3->{Banque} & \onslide<3->{18550} & \onslide<4->{Capital} & \onslide<4->{18550}\\
\hline
\onslide<5->{\textbf{Total}} & \onslide<5->{18550} & \onslide<5->{\textbf{Total}} & \onslide<5->{18550}\\
\hline
\end{tabular}
\end{frame}
\end{document}
```

[image]